# How to restrict user to change parameter in URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have an admin section where users can be restricted to search only selected countries. So if I choose user to be able only to search for USA and France, the IDs of these countries are stored in the table as string. So it would be `1,2`;

But lets say that user can search only in USA, so the ID is 1.

When user starts the search I get this value and store it in variable:

```
$searchableCountry  = explode(",", Input::get('searchableCountry'));
```

And this is the search condition:

```
if ($searchableCountry != null) {
            $results = $cl->Filter('country', $searchableCountry);
        }
```

And I get the URL something like this:
http://myapp.com/search?q=Adidas&searchableCountry=1

But user can edit the URL and change the `searchableCountry` value and search other countries as well. How can I avoid this? Can be this done with Session? If yes, please provide me an example?

btw for search I use this package https://github.com/sngrl/sphinxsearch

PS I have to use **GET** method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict your user can only do something, you shouldn't let them chose what they want, you must fix your rule instead.

```
$results = $cl->Filter('country', $config['country']['us']);
```

If you want to grant them permission to search in more country depending which level they are, you must add some more permission setting such as user level, so if they access http://myapp.com/search?q=Adidas&searchableCountry=3 you can return an error because they have not permission.

For example of my idea, not tested yet but should work.

```
<?php

//your user data
$user = json_decode('{
    "user_id" : NumberLong(1004109307),
    "fullname" : "Johnny",
    "email" : "xxx@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "123456789",
    "role" : "basic", //wich user can search US,FRANCE for country id is [1,2]
    "create_time" : NumberLong(1503537866)
}', true); //retun an array

//Your country id config somewhere
$country_list = array(
    'US' => 1,
    'FR' => 2,
    'JP' => 3,
    'CN' => 4,
);
//Your config somewhere
$searchable_country_config = array(
    'basic' => array(
        $country_list['US'], //1
        $country_list['FR'], //2
    ),
    'premium' => array(
        $country_list['JP'],
        $country_list['CN'],
    ),
);

$searchable_request = (Input::get('searchableCountry')) ? Input::get('searchableCountry') : 1; // 2 for example
$searchable_permission = $searchable_country_config[$user['role']];

//lets check that does this user have permission on their request
if(in_array($searchable_request,$searchable_permission))
{
    $results = $cl->Filter('country', $searchable_request);
} else {
    return response()->json(array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'You have not access for this country'
    ));
}
```

Comment: I do have user roles (Basic, Premium, Admin, etc...). But I'm not sure how can I connect this with URL restriction?!